# How to get the video ( flv ) from megavideo

Tags: php, algorithm, hyperlink, flv

There is any algorithm that prints the direction to the flv/other formats of megavideo links?

Comment: do you want to write your own leecher or just download a megavideo ... video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this script, but the magic numbers inside are correct.
http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/42944

Basically you have to find on the megavideo page the parameter s (for server) which determines on which host the file could be found.
And the parameters un,k1,k2 which you need to decrypt with the function from the url.

The resulting url will be:
'http://www'.$s.'.megavideo.com/files/'.$decrypted.'/'

Also note, that the s,un,k1,k2 can be cached for around 24h but then they will get invalid.